# Convert SQL to Pyspark

Tags: sql-server, pyspark, stored-procedures

I am trying to convert a SQL Server stored procedure to Pyspark code.

This is my SQL Server query:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#SUPPLYPARTS') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #SUPPLYPARTS;
END;

WITH A (TYPE, QUANTITY, ID, PARENTMSF, TOPPARENT) AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CAST(CHILDMSF AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS CHILDMSF,
        PARENTMSF,
        PARENTMSF,
        CAST(CONCAT(PARENTMSF, '-->', CHILDMSF) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS TRANSITION,
        QUANTITY,
        TYPE
    FROM 
        #BO BO(NOLOCK)
    WHERE 
        TYPE IN (0, 1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        CAST(B.CHILDMSF AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
        B.PARENTMSF,
        P.TOPPARENT, 
        B.TYPE, 
        CAST(CONCAT(A.TRANSITION, '-->', B.CHILDMSF) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS TRANSITION, 
        B.QUANTITY
    FROM 
        A
    JOIN 
        #BO B (NOLOCK) ON B.PARENTMSF = A.CHILDMSF
    WHERE  
        A.TYPE IN (0, 1)
)
SELECT DISTINCT *
INTO #SUPPLYPARTS
FROM A
WHERE TYPE IN (0, 1)
ORDER BY CHILDMSF 
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Below is the Pyspark code that I developed. Considering there is already root_df present

```
PARENT = root_df.select( \
    col("CHILDMSF").cast("string"), \
    col("ParentMsf").alias("PARENTMSF"), \
    col("ParentMsf").alias("TOPPARENT"),  \
    col("TYPE"), \
    col("QUANTITY"))\
    .withColumn("TRANSITION", concat(col("ParentMsf"), F.lit(' --> '), col("ChildMsf")).cast("string")) \
    .filter(col("TYPE").isin([0, 1])).distinct().alias("A")



BO= root_df.select("CHILDMSF","PARENTMSF",col("PARENTMSF").alias("TOPPARENT"),"TYPE","ISSPARABLE","QUANTITY").alias("B")


inter1 = PARENT.join(BO, col("P.CHILDMSF") == col("T.ParentMsf"), "inner") \
    .select(
        col("B.CHILDMSF"),
        col("B.PARENTMSF"),
        col("B.TOPPARENT"),
        col("B.TYPE"),
        col("B.QUANTITY"),
        col("A.TRANSITION"),
    ).withColumn("TRANSITION", concat(col("A.TRANSITION"), F.lit(' --> '), col("B.CHILDMSF")).cast("string")).drop("A.BOMPATH").filter(col("B.TYPE").isin([0, 1]))

BO1=PARENT.unionAll(inter1).orderBy("CHILDMSF").distinct()
BO_FINAL=BO1.filter(col("TYPE").isin([0, 1]))
BO_FINAL.count()
```

#A=P,B=T

While I am trying to validate data count between Sql and Pyspark,I am getting mismatch.Let me know if I m missing something in the logic

Comment: the first query is a recursive cte, i dont' think your pyspark code does any sort of recursion. perhaps this might be of some service: https://medium.com/globant/how-to-implement-recursive-queries-in-spark-3d26f7ed3bc9

Comment: Aside... the `NOLOCK` hint in `FROM #BO BO(NOLOCK)` is completely redundant. #temp tables only exist for the current connection so they can never experience contention from other SPIDs.